# How to combine two dependent projects in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I have a solution which has two projects. One is a static link library project, and another is a console project for demo. Now I want to create a MFC project to replace the console project, what should I do to configure the MFC project.

1. the MFC project need to use some classes in the .lib project.
2. I have set MFC project as start project and depend on the .lib project.
3. My platform is win7 + vs2015.
4. Actually, the solution is EasyPR, you can get it here [EasyPR](http://github.com/liuruoze/EasyPR).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Since it is your first question on SO, you might read [the guide on asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, I read it just now, and I still don't know how to describe my question clearly, as I'm not good at English. It is helpful if you can give some advice to modify my question.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the dependency to the static library is one step.

To compile the code you may need headers for the compiler. So the MFC projects may need settings for the compiler to define additional include paths.

You still need to configure the linker to use and find the library. To reference the library you may use a pragma comment lib. In the linker settings you may add an additional path for the libraries.

Or you may simply drag the lib into the solution explorer. The build mechanism will know how to treat a lib and will include it into the build process. The later will only work if you have 1 lib for release and debug.

If you have different libs for release and debug a advise you to use different names. You may adjust the project settings of the MFC program for debug and release differently.

Comment: Thanks! I have solved my problem with your suggestion. It's really helpful.